# ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting the error:     `ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG` when I'm executing the following code:

```
$i = 1;
    foreach ($data as $row){
        $timeCheck = explode(":", $this->ticket_model->count_time($row['start_date'], $row['end_date'], $row['start_time'], $row['end_time'], $row['pause_time'], $row['travel_time'], FALSE, FALSE));

        if($timeCheck[2] >= 10){
            echo $timeCheck[2]." is More<br/>";
        }else{
            echo $timeCheck[2]." is less<br/>";
        }

        if($i == 85){
            exit;
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

When I change the if statement inside the foreach as follow :

```
 $i = 1;
    foreach ($data as $row){
        $timeCheck = explode(":", $this->ticket_model->count_time($row['start_date'], $row['end_date'], $row['start_time'], $row['end_time'], $row['pause_time'], $row['travel_time'], FALSE, FALSE));

        if($timeCheck[2] >= 10){
            echo $timeCheck[2]." is More<br/>";
        }else{
            echo $timeCheck[2]." is less<br/>";
        }

        if($i == 5){
            exit;
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

It works just fine.

** Note that I only changed the if($i == 5) statement. **

Is there a way of fixing this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter but I'd assume it refers to HTTP headers. Open your browser's developer tools and inspect them to begin with.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? It seems to be a common enough problem, but I don't find any solution

Comment: I have no clue, this has been too far back. I think it was due to too much data going around but I cannot confirm this anymore.

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
for($i=0; sizeof($data) < 85; $i++){
  //and then modify $timeCheck sth like:
  $timeCheck = explode(":", $this->ticket_model->count_time($data[$i]['start_date'], $data[$i]['end_date'], $data[$i]['start_time'], $data[$i]['end_time'], $data[$i]['pause_time'], $data[$i]['travel_time'], FALSE, FALSE)); 
  //etc ... 
  //and the part with if($i > 85 ) should be excluded, as it is controlled with for loop
}
```

Comment: Using this fuction is still giving me the exact same error sadly.

Comment: maybe there is something with count_time that is issuing error?